# Rails: eager load on fetching associations, not on find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, eager-loading

I've got three nested models: `user` has many `plates` and `plate` has many `fruits`. I also have a `current_user` helper method that runs in the before filter to provide authentication. So when I get to my controller, I already have my `user` object. How can I load all the user's `plates` and `fruits` at once?

In other words, I'd like to do something like:

```
@plates = current_user.plates(include: :fruits)
```

How can I achieve this?

*I'm using Rails 3.1.3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use the provided `#includes` method on your relation.  DO NOT USE `#all` unless you intend to immediately work through the records, it will immediately defeat many forms of caching.

Perhaps something like: `@plates = current_user.plates.includes(:fruits)`

Unfortunately, there are portions of the Rails API that are not as well documented as they should be.  I would recommend checking out the following resources if you have any further questions about the Rails query interface:

- [Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
- [ActiveRecord::Relation Walkthrough (screencast)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough)

The query interface is possibly the most difficult part of the Rails stack to keep up with, especially with the changes made with Rails 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: The question did ask how to load _all_. :) AR#all can be used ok, unless you are already dealing with a site at scale, or you know you are.

Comment: It's considered best practice to defer the actual lookup from the database as long as possible.  #all defeats that practice.

Comment: #includes is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new([current_user], :plates => :fruit).run
```

To eager load associations after current_user was loased. The second argument can be anything you would normally pass to `includes`: a symbol, an array of symbols, a hash etc

Answer (score -2):

```
@plates = current_user.plates.all(:include => :fruits)
```

should do it.